# Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem for two-dimensional integrals

Tags: limits, physics, distribution-theory, complex-integration, cauchy-principal-value

I am doing some physics calculations, and I need to deal with integrals that can be reduced to this general form:
$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \int_{-a}^{b} \int_{-a}^{b} \frac{f(x,y)}{(x-i\epsilon)(y-i\epsilon)}dxdy, $$
where in my case $f(x,y)$ is symmetrical with respect to interchanging $x$ and $y$, and I also only need the real part of these integrals. I am not sure how the Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem would apply in such cases.

I tried to experiment numerically with the following expression instead:
$$ \lim_{\epsilon_1 \to 0^{+}} \lim_{\epsilon_2 \to 0^{+}} \int_{-a}^{b} \int_{-a}^{b} \frac{f(x,y)}{(x-i\epsilon_1)(y-i\epsilon_2)}dxdy, $$
since I was not completely sure if $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ had to be the same in my formulas. In the latter case, I could imagine applying the Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem twice, so I would obtain the following:
$$\begin{align} Re \left( \lim_{\epsilon_1 \to 0^{+}} \lim_{\epsilon_2 \to 0^{+}} \int_{-a}^{b} \int_{-a}^{b} \frac{f(x,y)}{(x-i\epsilon_1)(y-i\epsilon_2)}dxdy \right) & = \mathrm{PV}\int_{-a}^{b} \frac{1}{x} \left[ \mathrm{PV}\int_{-a}^{b} \frac{f(x,y)}{y} dy \right] dx \\ & - \pi^2f(0,0), \end{align}$$
but the corresponding numerical results seemed to be wrong from the physics point of view.

It is actually much more likely that I need to work with the first expression, and I suspect there are some subtleties that I am missing. How do I take the limit in the first equation properly when $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ coincide?

Also, if I consider a simple case of $f(x,y)=1$ and $a=b=1$, the answer seems to be $-\pi^2$, which I find rather strange, so I realize that I do not have a good intuition for this kind of things.

Any thoughts/ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have to be very careful with such integrals because of the [Poincare-Betrand theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Poincare-BertrandTheorem.html). The most transparent way to deal with these integrals is to perform a partial fraction expansion and separate the poles.

Comment: Igor, if I may ask, what is the physics reason that leads you to a conclusion, and what would that conclusion be? (My own experience is that physics-motivated conclusions are most often correct, although the rigorization thereof may need a fancier level of mathematics...)

Comment: @Fabian Thank you very much for the link! Very interesting, there is a subtlety even when \epsilon_1 and \epsilon_2 are different. Do I understand correctly that in my last formula I should remove the term "-\pi^2 f(x,y)"? That would also mean that for the case of f(x,y)=1 and a=b=1 the result is simply 0, which makes more sense to me. Unfortunately, this correction still does not solve my problem, could it be because of some additional complications when \epsilon_1 and \epsilon_2 coincide?

Comment: @paulgarrett My physics reasoning behind judging the numerical results as being "wrong" is very simple: the quantity I'm trying to calculate should be negative, and I obtain a positive result. Unfortunately, it's quite complicated since the functions f(x,y) are very messy, and I need to calculate a sum of many thousands of such integrals, but my code is working perfectly in cases when all the integrals are nice and proper, so I'm confident about all the other components. And the reason why I think that \epsilon_1 and \epsilon_2 coincide is because they come from the same photon propagator.

Comment: @IgorValuev, hm. Interesting. I'll think about this...

Comment: @IgorValuev: it is indeed true that the last term typically cancels one of the terms. The formula is correct even when the epsilon coincide. As I wrote in my last comment, instead of pondering and "handwaving" use the equality $1/(x-i \epsilon)/(y-i \epsilon) = 1/(x-y) [1/(y-i\epsilon) -1/(x-i\epsilon)]$ and each of the two terms is conventional and you can use Sokhotski–Plemelj on them.

Comment: @Fabian But aren't we introducing a new singularity in this way, when $x=y$? How should I deal with it?

Comment: @IgorValuev: There is no new singularity as for $x=y$ the term in the square brackets vanish. So you have to calculate the integral "together" and you are not allowed to split it up into two integrals. However, you can use Sokhotski–Plemelj on each of the terms without problems.

Comment: @Fabian Good point, this makes sense! However, I'm still confused. In my understanding, using Sokhotski–Plemelj on the first term implies taking the integral in $y$, whereas doing it on the second term corresponds to taking integral in $x$. How is it possible to do something like this without splitting the integral into two? Whatever I'm trying to write down doesn't make any sense. I must be missing something fundamental here. Could you please explain what you mean by "using Sokhotski–Plemelj on each of the terms"?

Comment: @IgorValuev: I mean using the identity $1/(x- i\epsilon) = \mathcal{P} 1/ +i \pi \delta(x)$. In any case, I do not understand what you mean that whatever you write down does not make sense. [Here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Poincare-BertrandTheorem.html)  exactly your integral is evaluated -- the result is simply a mathematical fact (not sure what it means to make sense). My comments where just to indicate how such a result can be derived in a pedestrian manner. Maybe [this](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jam/2012/969685/) is useful?

Comment: @Fabian Yes, I understand that you actually answered my question perfectly in your first comment already, so all my follow-up questions are just for gaining some more understanding :) When I write it together: $1/(x-y)[\mathcal{P}1/y+i \pi\delta(y)-\mathcal{P}1/x-i \pi\delta(x)]$, I don't know how to interpret this kind of expression and how to proceed further and obtain the final result. I don't know much about generalized functions, so I would really appreciate it if you could give some more details on this "pedestrian derivation". These kinds of things are extremely useful for physicists!

Comment: @Fabian In any case, your answer was extremely valuable, and I would like to make it more visible. I'm new to the website, so I'm not sure what would be the best way. Would you like to write it as an answer, so I could accept it, or should I just add an edit to my question summarizing the main point?

Comment: @IgorValuev: I took some time to write up a reply. Please feel free to comment, suggest changes, or accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Prelude:*

The product of two principal value integrals (denoted by $\mathcal{P}$ in the following) is special due to the fact that in a double integral the order of integration matters. In particular, the Poincare-Bertrand theorem states that
$$\int\!dx\,\frac{\mathcal{P}}{x-u}\int\!dy\,\frac{\mathcal{P}}{y-x} f(x,y) = \int\!dy\,\int\!dx\,\frac{\mathcal{P}}{x-u}\frac{\mathcal{P}}{y-x} f(x,y) - \pi^2 f(u,u)\,; \tag{1}$$
for a proof see, e.g., [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-009-9994-7_3). The Poincare-Bertrand theorem is important, as it shows that the [Hilbert transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform)
$$ \mathcal{H}(f)(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int\!\frac{\mathcal{P}}{y-x}f(y)$$
is an involution. Indeed
$$ \mathcal{H}(\mathcal{H}(f))(u) =\frac{1}{\pi^2} \int\!dx\,\frac{\mathcal{P}}{u-x}\int\!\frac{\mathcal{P}}{y-x}f(y) = f(u)$$
due to (1) and the fact that
$$\int\!dx\,\frac{\mathcal{P}}{u-x}\frac{\mathcal{P}}{y-x} = 0\,.$$

*Main:*

In your specific case, it is not possible to simply use the Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem for a double integral due to the fact that the double principal value integral depends on the order of integration (see above). In particular, the [Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem for double integrals](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Poincare-BertrandTheorem.html) that takes care of the Poincare-Bertrand theorem is
$$ \lim_{\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2 \to 0^+} \frac{1}{x-i \epsilon_1}\frac{1}{y-i \epsilon_2} = \left[ \frac{\mathcal{P}}{x} +i \pi \delta(x) \right] \left[ \frac{\mathcal{P}}{y} +i \pi \delta(y) \right] + \pi^2 \delta(x)\delta(y)\,. $$
Note that the last term, due to the Poincare-Bertrand theorem, cancels the product of $\delta$-distributions.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed answer! I just wanted to clarify one thing: what do you mean when you say that the double principal value integral is "undefined"? Or, speaking in terms of practical calculations, is it still correct that the product of $\frac{\mathcal{P}}{x}$ and $\frac{\mathcal{P}}{y}$ in your last formula means taking the following integral: $\mathrm{PV}\int_{-a}^{b} \frac{1}{x} \left[ \mathrm{PV}\int_{-a}^{b} \frac{f(x,y)}{y} dy \right] dx$, like in my original question?

Comment: @IgorValuev: I changed the language from "undefined" to "depends on the order of integration" to make the text more clear. Note that in the last integral (and in your question), the double principal value does in fact not depend on the order of integration as the principal values are not nested (different from Eq. (1)). Still, you obtain the Poincare-Betrand correction term due to the fact that Sokhotski–Plemelj gives a wrong result for the integral close to $x=y=0$ (due to the fact that at this point two principal values contribute).